# How to get each data value pairs of an object within object using object.keys and map method

Tags: javascript, object

i want to access each data value pair of an object which is inside an object using object.keys and map method and store it in a new array. Below is the example code snippet.

```
{
item1: {name: 'hello', value: '10'},
item2: {name: 'hello1', value: '20'},
item3: {name: 'world', value: '30'},
}
```

To do so i used the below code

```
values = (object) => {
    var data = [];
    for (var key in object) {
        data.push(object[key]);
    }
    return data;
};
```

I would like to do that using map method on object how could i do it. thanks.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to the values corresponding to each keys within the object, all you need to do is use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like

```
values = (object) => {
    return Object.values(object);
};
```

However if you still want a mapped version using `Object.keys()`, you can write it like

```
values = (object) => {
    return Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]);
};
```